# How do i search directories and find files that match regex?

Tags: python, regex, linux, file, directory

I recently started getting into Python and I am having a hard time searching through directories and matching files based on a regex that I have created.

Basically I want it to scan through all the directories in another directory and find all the files that ends with `.zip` or `.rar` or `.r01` and then run various commands based on what file it is.

```
import os, re

rootdir = "/mnt/externa/Torrents/completed"

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    if re.search('(w?.zip)|(w?.rar)|(w?.r01)', files):
        print "match: " . files
```

Comment: paste your traceback please

Comment: `w?` optionally matches a literal `w`.  `.` matches any character, including a dot. And without anchors, you match "a.rar.txt". To match zip or rar at the end, try: `r'(\.zip|\.rar)$'`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
import os
import re

rootdir = "/mnt/externa/Torrents/completed"
regex = re.compile('(.*zip$)|(.*rar$)|(.*r01$)')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
  for file in files:
    if regex.match(file):
       print(file)
```

**CODE BELLOW ANSWERS QUESTION IN FOLLOWING COMMENT**

> That worked really well, is there a way to do this if match is found on regex group 1 and do this if match is found on regex group 2 etc ? – nillenilsson

```
import os
import re

regex = re.compile('(.*zip$)|(.*rar$)|(.*r01$)')
rx = '(.*zip$)|(.*rar$)|(.*r01$)'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("../Documents"):
  for file in files:
    res = re.match(rx, file)
    if res:
      if res.group(1):
        print("ZIP",file)
      if res.group(2):
        print("RAR",file)
      if res.group(3):
        print("R01",file)
```

It might be possible to do this in a nicer way, but this works.

Comment: That worked really well, is there a way to do this if match is found on regex group 1 and do this if match is found on regex group 2 etc ?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the code. Be aware that there might be nicer way to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this pattern `egex = re.compile('(w.*rar)|(s.*txt)|(\.py$)', flags=re.IGNORECASE)`. It works for the first two groups but doesn't return the py files.

Comment: Be aware that `(\.py$)` will only match the extension, hence `re.match()` will not see it as a match.

Answer (score 10):

Given that you are a beginner, I would recommend using `glob` in place of a quickly written file-walking-regex matcher.

### Snippets of functions using `glob` and a `file-walking-regex matcher`

The below snippet contains two file-regex searching functions (one using `glob` and the other using a custom file-walking-regex matcher). The snippet also contains a "stopwatch" function to time the two functions.

```py
import os
import sys
from datetime import timedelta
from timeit import time
import os
import re
import glob

def stopwatch(method):
    def timed(*args, **kw):
        ts = time.perf_counter()
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        te = time.perf_counter()
        duration = timedelta(seconds=te - ts)
        print(f"{method.__name__}: {duration}")
        return result
    return timed

@stopwatch
def get_filepaths_with_oswalk(root_path: str, file_regex: str):
    files_paths = []
    pattern = re.compile(file_regex)
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(root_path):
        for file in files:
            if pattern.match(file):
                files_paths.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    return files_paths


@stopwatch
def get_filepaths_with_glob(root_path: str, file_regex: str):
    return glob.glob(os.path.join(root_path, file_regex))
```

### Comparing runtimes of the above functions

On using the above two functions to find 5076 files matching the regex `filename_*.csv` in a dir called `root_path` (containing 66,948 files):

```py
>>> glob_files = get_filepaths_with_glob(root_path, 'filename_*.csv')
get_filepaths_with_glob: 0:00:00.176400

>>> oswalk_files = get_filepaths_with_oswalk(root_path,'filename_(.*).csv')
get_filepaths_with_oswalk: 0:03:29.385379
```

The `glob` method is much faster and the code for it is shorter.

### For your case

For your case, you can probably use something like the following to get your `*.zip`,`*.rar` and `*.r01` files:

```py
files = []
for ext in ['*.zip', '*.rar', '*.r01']:
    files += get_filepaths_with_glob(root_path, ext)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative using `glob`.

```py
from pathlib import Path

rootdir = "/mnt/externa/Torrents/completed"
for extension in 'zip rar r01'.split():
    for path in Path(rootdir).glob('*.' + extension):
        print("match: " + path)
```

Comment: not truly an answer, since it doesn't do regex matching

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path

def glob_re(path, regex="", glob_mask="**/*", inverse=False):
    p = Path(path)
    if inverse:
        res = [str(f) for f in p.glob(glob_mask) if not re.search(regex, str(f))]
    else:
        res = [str(f) for f in p.glob(glob_mask) if re.search(regex, str(f))]
    return res
```

NOTE: per default it will recursively scan all subdirectories. If you want to scan only the current directory then you should explicitly specify `glob_mask="*"`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am a newbie, can you put an example of how to use the function?

Comment: I tried `print(glob_re('.', '(s?.txt)|(w?.rar)', '*', False))` but I got unmatching file names in the list of output

Comment: @YasserKhalil, what kind of file names are you looking for? Are you looking in the current directory only (without subdirectories)?

Comment: Yes in the current directory only and the files I need are the text files that start with s and the rar files that start with w and also I need any python file with the extension `.py`

Comment: @YasserKhalil, try this RegEx: `r"^(?:s.*\.txt|w.*\.rar|.*\.py)$"`

Comment: I got this error `OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:`

Comment: I tried this `print(glob_re(r"^(?:s.*\.txt|w.*\.rar|.*\.py)$", "*", False))` and I got `ValueError: Unacceptable pattern: False`

Comment: @YasserKhalil, the first parameter should be the path, second - the RegEx and so on... `print(glob_re(path=".", regex=r"^(?:s.*\.txt|w.*\.rar|.*\.py)$", glob_mask="*", inverse =False))`